# client_secret compromised, options?

Tags: security, oauth2, app

We have no evidence to believe, but are acting as if, the client_secret has been compromised on our Salesforce OAuth 2 App.  I was wondering what our options are:

- is it possible to generate a new client_secret that can be used with existing refresh_tokens to generate new access_tokens?
- is using the existing client_secret acceptable as the URL rules in Salesforce will prevent misuse?
- if it's not possible to generate a new client_secret would we have to create a whole new App to acquire one?

Thanks!

Comment: I have not seen _any_ reference to re-generating a client_secret logged in to Salesforce.com and a google for re-generating client_secret salesforce returns nothing.  Also when I have removed OAuth authentication from a test app and then re-added it, the client_key and secret remained the same.  Also for clarification this is in an app we wrote, packaging I do not think applies to us.

Comment: I think I am incorrect here, what I thought was a generate new secret link (from memory) was actually the "click to reveal' - Deleting my comments as I believe I am just incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Log a case with Salesforce, they should be able to help you generate a new client_secret.

Comment: Unfortunately apparently we do not pay Salesforce enough to warrant developer support.